# How to assign the values for dict(keys and values) into a new list? and also how to print the keys and values in the string dictionary?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I would like to print the keys and values of a string of dictionaries. For example,

```
a = [{'1': '0'}, {'9': '2'}, {'4': '3'}, {'3': '5'}, {'0': '7'}, [], [], [], []]
```

I tried this :

```
for x in a:
    for y in x.values():
        print(y)
```

not working

```
for x in a:
    for y in x.itervalues():
        print(y)
```

not working

```
for x in a:
    for y in x.items():
        print(y)
```

not working

Anyway to print it like this? :

```
1 0
9 2
4 3
3 5
0 7
```

or

```
keys = 1,9,4,3,0
values = 0,2,3,5,7
```

Comment: `a` is a mixed list of dictionaries and lists, not a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to filter out non-dictionaries using list comprehension, then convert the dictionaries into key-value tuples, and separate the keys and values with `zip`:

```
k,v = zip(*[list(x.items())[0] for x in a if isinstance(x, dict)])
print(k,v)
#('1', '9', '4', '3', '0') ('0', '2', '3', '5', '7')
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you want the side by side key/value pair output, then you can do something like this (code would need to be altered if any of your dictionaries were going to contain more than one key/value pair):

```
for x in a:
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        # "if isinstance" is here just to ignore the lists in your list,
        # you may want to do something else with those
        print(x.keys(), x.values())

# (['1'], ['0'])
# (['9'], ['2'])
# (['4'], ['3'])
# (['3'], ['5'])
# (['0'], ['7'])
```

If you need to handle more than one key/value pair in the dictionary items and print just the values (minus the formatting), then something like this:

```
for x in a:
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        tups = x.items()
        for tup in tups:
            print('{} {}'.format(tup[0], tup[1]))

# 1 0
# 9 2
# 4 3
# 3 5
# 0 7
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Yea, this works too. I tried to make another different dictionary to contain more keys to test.

Comment: Sir is there a way to print it in integer with only 1, 9, 4, 3, 0 and not in another list like above?

Comment: Do you mean a way to remove the list formatting (parentheses and single quotes)? And then are you trying to print the keys in a row first followed by the values in a row like the answer from @DYZ or in the stacked key/value pair output like this answer?

Comment: Yes. I would prefer it to be only in integer if possible. I tried this:list(map(int,(x.keys()))) but it output another list: [1][2] like this. Is there a way to make it only 1 2

Comment: Glad you got it. Added an example to my answer that also handles it if there is more than key/value pair in the dictionary for anyone else that might come looking.